# After install owin package to my vs2012 i cant found my create owin startup class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, chat, owin

I have installed Microsoft Owin package to my VS2012 but while creating a new class i could not see my owin start up class for creating a new class.

Answer (score 0):

It should be created by the SignalR package I think?

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRConfig))]
namespace MyApp.App_Start
{
    public static class SignalRConfig
    {
        public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```